# How to get file names from Directory as it is it exist in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to extract all file names in a order as they exist in window explorer. I have googled and found many answers but this did not work. I have a file names in following order:

```
 video_1
 video_2
 video_3
 video_10
 video_15
 video_20
 video_21
```

I want in the same order but the result comes  in the following form.

```
 video_1
 video_10
 video_10
 video_2
 video_20
 video_21
```

I have tried the following codes:

```
var fileNames= Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*" + fileExtension) //Not worked
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(basePath);
var filenames = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTIme).ToArray(); //Not worked
```

Can someone tell me how i can do this?

Comment: well `.OrderBy(p => p.CreationTIme)` wont work as you order them by creation time.. try to sort them with filename..

Comment: Filename also not working

Comment: @Steve - this might be a duplicate question but not of the one you closed with. That one was for VB.Net and thus not an exact dup. Will search to find one in C#

Comment: The answer is in C# and VB.NET. Let me say however that your solution is faster.

Comment: Actually Special characters are blocking the required order. so try this 

    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("");
    var files = info.GetFiles()
                .OrderBy(p => p.FullName.ToString("N"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the order is "incorrect" is because the names are strings and therefore are ordered as strings. What you want is to order by the numeric part of it:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("");
var files = info.GetFiles()
                .OrderBy(p => p.FullName.Split('_')[0])
                .ThenBy(p => int.Parse(p.FullName.Split('_')[1]));
```

If you are not sure the format is exactly like that (with a `_` and then a valid number) then you can:

```
Func<string, int, int> parseIntOrDefault = (input, defaultValue) =>
{
    int value = defaultValue;
    int.TryParse(input, out value);
    return value;
};

var result = from file in info.GetFiles()
             let sections = file.FullName.Split('_')
             orderby sections[0], sections.Length == 2 ?
                 parseIntOrDefault(sections[1], int.MaxValue) : int.MaxValue
             select file;
```

Comment: If @Umer wants to sort like the file system does I would think this would be a more appropriate answer to his question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601834/c-implementation-of-or-alternative-to-strcmplogicalw-in-shlwapi-dll. The actual question contains the code I believe he should use. Although their is nothing wrong with your answer it just doesn't continue to work if he ever changes his format.

Comment: @MaxYoung it works for me. Finally. Please write this comment as answer so that i can mark it and other can get help from it

Comment: @Umer I cant since the duplicate was accepted. I would just upvote that question. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks again man.