# JSON.NET multiple orderby in JArray with Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, json.net

I have the following JSON and I'm wondering if it's possible to do a multiple `OrderBy` using Linq.

```
var body = @"[{                            
        ""portOfLoading"": ""GOT"",
        ""bookingResponses"":[{
                ""bookingNumber"": ""11"",
                ""comment"": ""LOFO"",
                ""customerReference"": ""3423462"",
                ""departureDate"": ""2017-04-10"",
                ""departureTime"": ""18:00"",
                ""description"": ""desc"",
                ""length"": ""7482"",
                ""netWeight"": ""12345"",
                ""plugin"": ""true"",
                ""resourceCode"": ""CONT26"",
                ""route"": ""GOTZEE"",
                ""status"": ""Price missing"",
                ""unitNumber"": ""ABC123"",
                ""width"": ""0""
            }
        ]
    }
      ,
        {

        ""portOfLoading"": ""GOT"",
        ""bookingResponses"":[{
                ""bookingNumber"": ""3"",
                ""comment"": ""LOFO"",
                ""customerReference"": ""3423462"",
                ""departureDate"": ""2017-04-10"",
                ""departureTime"": ""18:00"",
                ""description"": ""desc"",
                ""length"": ""7482"",
                ""netWeight"": ""12345"",
                ""plugin"": ""true"",
                ""resourceCode"": ""CONT26"",
                ""route"": ""GOTZEE"",
                ""status"": ""Price missing"",
                ""unitNumber"": ""ABC123"",
                ""width"": ""0""
            }
        ]
    }
      ,{
        ""portOfLoading"": ""OUL"",
        ""bookingResponses"":[{
                ""bookingNumber"": ""7"",
                ""comment"": ""STANDBY"",
                ""customerReference"": ""3423462"",
                ""departureDate"": ""2017-04-10"",
                ""departureTime"": ""18:00"",
                ""description"": ""desc"",
                ""length"": ""7482"",
                ""netWeight"": ""12345"",
                ""plugin"": ""true"",
                ""resourceCode"": ""CONT26"",
                ""route"": ""OULZEE"",
                ""status"": ""Price missing"",
                ""unitNumber"": ""ABC123"",
                ""width"": ""0""
            }
            ]
        },{
        ""portOfLoading"": ""ZEE"",
        ""bookingResponses"":[{
                ""bookingNumber"": ""3"",
                ""comment"": ""STANDBY"",
                ""customerReference"": ""3423462"",
                ""departureDate"": ""2017-04-10"",
                ""departureTime"": ""18:00"",
                ""description"": ""desc"",
                ""length"": ""7482"",
                ""netWeight"": ""12345"",
                ""plugin"": ""true"",
                ""resourceCode"": ""CONT26"",
                ""route"": ""ZEEGOT"",
                ""status"": ""Price missing"",
                ""unitNumber"": ""ABC123"",
                ""width"": ""0""
            }
            ]
        },{
        ""portOfLoading"": ""GOT"",
        ""bookingResponses"":[{
                ""bookingNumber"": ""10"",
                ""comment"": ""STANDBY"",
                ""customerReference"": ""3423462"",
                ""departureDate"": ""2017-04-10"",
                ""departureTime"": ""18:00"",
                ""description"": ""desc"",
                ""length"": ""7482"",
                ""netWeight"": ""12345"",
                ""plugin"": ""true"",
                ""resourceCode"": ""CONT26"",
                ""route"": ""GOTZEE"",
                ""status"": ""Price missing"",
                ""unitNumber"": ""ABC123"",
                ""width"": ""0""
            }
            ]
        }
    ]";
```

So far I've got the 'first' orderby to work, like this:

```
JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(body);
JArray sortQuery = new JArray(jsonVal.OrderBy(obj => obj["portOfLoading"]));
```

After `"portOfLoading"` I want to orderBy `"bookingNumber"`. I've tried using `ThenBy` and so on but never got it to work. Thanks

Comment: What if `"bookingResponses"` has several items beneath it? what is your expected output?

Comment: you can use `.ThenBy(obj2 => obj2["bookingNumber"] ` I think.

Comment: @Achilles you can't, see Gilad's answer for why that's insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `"bookingResponses"` always has a single item in it as in your example do the following:

```
JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(body);
JArray sortQuery = new JArray(jsonVal.OrderBy(obj => obj["portOfLoading"])
                                     .ThenBy(obj => int.Parse(obj["bookingResponses"].FirstOrDefault()?["bookingNumber"].ToString())));
```

Reason for adding the `Int.Parse` is because without it the `"bookingNumber"` will be ordered by the textual ordering of it (as strings) instead of numeric ordering. Leading to an order of: 1,10,11,3. If it is not certain that the values are always a valid integer (and thus cause an `InvalidCastException`) one can do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43449166/6400526)